# mvn clean install fails inside of Dockerfile

Tags: docker, maven

I'm new to docker and I'm trying to clone a repo then running mvn clean install
the when I build my dockerfile , mvn clean install starts for awhile then eventually exits with exit code 1

```
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c mvn clean install]: exit code: 1
```

My docker file is the following

```
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-11-slim AS build
WORKDIR /src
# Update aptitude with new repo
RUN apt-get update

# Install git software 
RUN apt-get install -y git

# cloning eclipse-hawkbit rep
RUN git clone https://github.com/eclipse/hawkbit.git /project/hawkbit
WORKDIR /project/hawkbit
RUN ls
# generating the binary
RUN mvn clean install
```

can someone help me out please :D

Comment: Does “mvn” alone work (but don’t know what to do)?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen , it works but doesnt finish , during the process it fails